# Push count increasing when Pull in SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am new to git and sourcetree. I am facing a problem whenever I do pull operation in Sourcetree tool. If I am receiving 3 changesets by pulling latest, then this same count is increasing in Push icon. Look this image for more info:

[image]

I do not understand why should I push the same changes I have pulled... Please help.

Comment: Are you using a merge-based pull or rebase-based pull? Anyways, I've noticed that Sourcetree gets lost when many merge occurs and often displays a wrong number of changes to be pushed. Sourcetree's vocabulary is also very confusing in many cases and not consequent with GIT's vocabulary. If you're unsure about what you are pushing I can recommend you to use "git status" in console which will never fail you "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/abcde' by X commits." and see when it differs from Sourcetree

Comment: "git status"  command saying, "On branch master <br/> Your branch is ahead of origin/ABCD" where ABCD is my old branch. And I have been switched to new branch "master"

Comment: If I push these 36 commits to my current branch "master", will it create any problem in others code? out of these 36, I have to push some commits to "master" branch.

Comment: Doesn't `git status` mention how many commits ahead you are? I just thought of one other thing that could confuse sourcetree. If you have often been doing pull, you have created a merge commit everytime there was something to pull. And now you are trying to push all of you commits + the merge commits.

Comment: To answer your question, it shouldn't be a problem to push your code to others, the merge commit is the commit that ensures that your branch and "other"'s branch were compatible. Should the merge not bring satisfaction it is still possible to re-do it afterwards.

Comment: And of course if someone pushed something before you did push your merge commit, you will have to do (or most likely, git will do it for you) create a new merge commit between the former merge and the new commits from remote before you can push it.

Comment: How to avoid this increasing push count when doing pull?

Comment: 1. Only `pull` when you are going to push. Pull does `fetch` + `merge` every time, maybe you only wanted to do `git fetch`? 2. Rebase instead of merging when you pull. Either with `git pull -r` or I think there is a checkbox in Sourcetree's interface if you want to achieve this.

Comment: It's kind of hard for me to tell you what you should do when you don't explain what you are trying to achieve. My advice is that you read a little bit about git and how it works, having basic knowledge about GIT's philosophy will help you a lot when you will need to make decisions about what feature to use.

Comment: Thanks!! this make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a pull, git does more than just fetch the latest commits. It also, if necessary, merges your last local commit with the latest remote commit. This merge creates a new commit on your local machine, which is why you are more "ahead" after the pull. This is all totally normal; go ahead and push.